# Android google search results to json ou xml

Tags: android, xml, json, search

I need to get google search results to show in my android app. How i can get that results?

In this moment its easy to me if results can be get in json or xml.

Someone know how to do this?
Thank you and sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go through this:

http://code.google.com/p/gsearch-java-client/

Comment: And where i can find Ajax Search API to import gsearch?